# how to store string value pairs in array format in angular 6

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am getting responses like:

Do you Have Multiple locations?,yes,How many Physical locations?,4

The required format is:

```
[Do you Have Multiple locations?,yes],[How many Physical locations?,4],....
```

Can anyone recommend any suggestion?

Comment: Does it need to be an array? Can it not be an object? `[{"question": "Do you Have Multiple locations", "answer": "yes" }, etc]`

Comment: Object will also work fine. Thank you for your suggestion

Comment: @user184994 can you guide me how can i get the array values as you mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a class like,

```
export class MyClass{
    question: string;
    answer: string;
}
```

and then create an array of the above object as,

`myList : MyClass[] = []`;

push the object to this array by,

```
this.myList.push(yourObject);
```

Comment: sorry i am unable to upvote as my reputation is below 15. I will upvote it in coming days.